# Middle Egyptian name for Seshat: Sšꜣt or Zẖꜣt?

Tags: sound-change, transcription, egyptian

Trying to learn Middle Egyptian myself, I just found out there are two transcriptions for the word  (to scribe): *√sšꜣ* and *√zẖꜣ*:

- In some corpora on [Thesaurus Linguae Aegyptiae website](https://aaew.bbaw.de/tla/servlet/GetWcnRefs?u=guest&f=0&l=0&ll=*600375&wt=y&lr=0&mo=1&db=0&of=0) the inscription of the word was  *zš*, though its transcription is *zẖꜣ* on the website. But on the same website the transcription of the name of Seshat is mostly [Sšꜣt](https://aaew.bbaw.de/tla/servlet/GetWcnDetails?u=guest&f=0&l=0&wn=144620&db=0).
- The name of Seshat was inscribed as  *Sšꜣt* in [Pyramid Text 616b T](https://www.lib.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/eos/eos_page.pl?DPI=100&callnum=PJ1553.A1_1908_cop3&object=342).
- Faulkner (1964) lists *sš* "scribe" in the dictionary but there was no entry for *zẖ*.
- If my reading is correct, [Vycichl (1983)](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairetymo0000vyci/page/204/mode/2up) says  *zš* should probably be read *zẖ*.
- Allen (2000) transcribes  as *√zẖꜣ*.

My questions are:

1. Why is it transcribed as *zẖꜣ*?
2. If there was a sound change, what period was the word read *zẖꜣ*? (I know that /z/ and /s/ merged in Middle Egyptian, but have no idea about /š/ and /ẖ/.)
3. If I know correct, the name of Seshat is derived from the word . What would be the proper transcription for "Seshat" in Middle Egyptian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still debated.

As you mention, "scribe" was written with the door bolt and the pool of water (*z-š*) in the earliest inscriptions. As a result, Budge proposed the reading *zš* for the "scribe" logogram, and this was widely accepted for a long time (so that's also what you see in Faulkner and Hoch, and the classic *Wörterbuch*).

But some authors, including Vycichl and Allen, now believe that this was a misreading. The Coptic form is ⲥⲁϧ (*sax*), and ϧ (*x*) isn't what we'd expect as a reflex of *š*. They argue that the pool of water was sometimes used to represent *ẖ* in the earliest texts, before the animal belly caught on, and thus the word was actually *zẖ* or *zẖꜣ*. This would explain the Coptic reflex. This interpretation was also adopted by Loprieno and the *Thesaurus Linguae Aegyptiae*.

This root was almost exclusively written with the logogram Y3/Y4 after the Old Kingdom period (or with R20 in Seshat's name), so further evidence on the pronunciation is lacking. The older *zš* reading is still very common, which is why you find e.g. the program named JSesh. But consensus seems to be slowly and steadily shifting toward *zẖ(ꜣ)*.

Personally, I would transcribe the name as *zẖꜣ.t*, but use "Seshat" as the English version, since it's what non-Egyptologists are used to.

Comment: To be fair, I’d say non-Egyptologists aren’t used to _any_ form of this name, because they’ve simply never heard of Seshat. I’d judge my knowledge of Egyptian names as definitely above average for non-Egyptologists, and I’ve never heard of her.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Fair; perhaps amend "are used to" to "can find on Wikipedia or the like".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's a bit difficult to dig more about the "the pool of water was used, before the animal belly caught on" part. Could you give me a reference?

Comment: @puzzlet I believe that's Vycichl's argument, but my French isn't good enough to give more detail I'm afraid.